# Как передать массив в varargs?

Tags: java, android

Я использую `AsynTask` и он принимает на параметр на вход `varargs`.

Как передать массив в `varargs`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Класс `AsyncTask` использует дженерики при создании класса наследника - первый параметр - тип входных данных, второй - данные для оповещения о прогрессе задачи, третий - тип выходных данных.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i=0; i<params.length; i++)
                list.add(params[i]);

            return null;
        }
}
```

Передать массив в AsyncTask можно так

```
String[] arr = new String[] {"one", "two", "three"};
new MyAsyncTask().execute(arr);
```

либо

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute("one", "two", "three", "four");
```

Comment: Чет мне кажется, что это не будет работать... Вы указываете `AsyncTask` который принимает `String` , а передаете ему `String[]`... Не так ли?

Comment: первый параметр String это только указание классу, на ТИП входных данных, а передать вы можете любое количество строк.

Comment: Вы попробуйте, а потом нам расскажите)

Comment: Да я ошибся, все верно

Answer (score 1):

Массив можно просто передавать в качестве аргумента varargs, как будто это перечисленные через запятую элементы этого массива. Например:

```
static  void doSomething(String ... strings) {
    for (String string : strings) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    doSomething("s1", "s2", "s3"); // (1)

    String [] arr = {"s1", "s2", "s3"};
    doSomething(arr);   // (2)
}
```

Вызовы метода `doSomething()` в строках (1) и (2) дают одинаковый результат.

Comment: Чет мне кажется, что это не будет работать... Вы указываете AsyncTask который принимает String , а передаете ему String[]... Не так ли?

Comment: А насчет первого, то не совсем удобно так как у меня есть массив... и паскладывать его на его составляющие не совсем удобно...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Это работает. Я попробовала. Это скопировано из класса, работу которого я проверяла в Idea. А первое (с перечислением 3-х элементов) предложено для иллюстрации эквивалентности обоих  вызовов.

Comment: Да,  все верно это работает.  Я ошибся.  Спасибо!